# Spring state machine as a message bus

Tags: spring-statemachine, message-bus

I am currently checking spring state machine as an implementation of a custom service bus.
I have 2 questions :

1. How do I configure a transition based on timer where the time will be based on the model. For example :  if I want to delay a message delivery to time which is the start time of the model object (and could be different in different messages). that is without implementing the scheduling myself.
2. I liked the API but is spring state machine suitable (performance wise), to implement a message bus, which handles hundreds (or even thousands) of messages per second in some situations.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would not try to use statemachine as a CEP engine because it's not designed for that role. There's real engines like [esper](https://github.com/espertechinc/esper) which will do better job as a raw CEP handler.

Statemachine is more suited to handle more complex things what a single event could cause in your system when you need better state handling.